# How can you share Typescript types and JSON schemas between micro-service code repos?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, microservices, schema

If you have multiple code repositories that rely on shared data types, and you want to ensure each repository stays in sync with each other, what are some of the best options to ensure that you're not just manually redefining each type (meaning they can fall out of sync) in each repo?

I've done some initial research but want to see what general consensus and people's preferences are.

Comment: Publish a shared package and have each service depend on it.

Comment: This is what stands out to me as the best option. Are there any explicit downsides to this approach? Any popular alternatives?

Comment: Well, it depends on you work environment, level of collaboration, and whether or not you need multi-version support. Also, if any of your projects are general purpose libraries. For example: say one project is a webservice hosted at at "https://api.test.com/v1/" that exposes APIs whose shapes are reflected by your shared types at some point but then you add "https://api.test.com/v2/" which different response shapes. In such a situation, you you either need to create another set of shared types while maintaining the old one for existing clients that haven't upgraded. Semver/packaging is cleaner